# FeathersJS: Cannot add routes after initializing app

Tags: feathersjs

Newbie FeathersJS user here. I'm obviously missing some key bit of understanding.

I'm trying to create a simple REST API using MySQL models. I'm attempting to follow the code structure referenced by the docs in [this issue thread](https://github.com/feathersjs/generator-feathers/issues/94#issuecomment-204165134). Routes I define in my initial `app.use()` block work, but not those defined after it. Partial code here, rest [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/skypanther/3dd3481be67b1b5edc14ad96741fc304)

```
const app = feathers();
app.configure(configuration(path.join(__dirname, '..')));

app.use(compress())
  .options('*', cors())
  .use(cors())
  .use(favicon(path.join(app.get('public'), 'favicon.ico')))
  /* THIS ROUTE WORKS FINE */
  .use('/', serveStatic(app.get('public')))
  .use(bodyParser.json())
  .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }))
  .configure(hooks())
  .configure(rest())
  .configure(socketio())
  .configure(models)
  .configure(services)
  .configure(middleware);

const appModels = app.get('models');
const beerOptions = {
  Model: appModels.beer,
  paginate: {
    default: 15,
    max: 50
  }
};

/* NEITHER OF THESE ROUTES WORK */
app.use('/beer', service(beerOptions));
// IF YOU DELETE THE DEFINITION ABOVE AND UNCOMMENT 
// THIS NEXT LINE, THE ROOT URL GIVES A 404
// app.use('/', serveStatic(app.get('public')));
```

I don't get any errors when `npm start`ing the app. But, my `/beer` route just 404s as does any route defined there. I've been through the guides looking for the source of my misunderstanding. But I'm kinda stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like in Express the order of middleware (and additionally for Feathers, `configure` calls) matters. In the case of the generated application, `.configure(middleware);` *has* to run last after everything else because it registers a `notFound` handler which will throw a 404 error. Any middleware after that (except the error handler) will never run.

Comment: Why would that be? It clearly answered the OPs question?